# top and bottom in display : inline css

Tags: css, position, margin, display, inline-styles

why are top and bottom margins affected when I use `display : inline;` in css for designing my web page ?

Output:

[image]

Inspect Element:

[image: inspect element style]

I'm trying to center the image using `margin : auto` with `display : inline` property which should center the image with respect to left and right margin of the web page.

So, please tell me the reason.

My HTML code

```html
<div class="middle-container">
        <div class="profile">
          <img class= "profile-image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pz7b9.png" alt="">
          <h2>Hello.</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vitae volutpat, dui conubia, dolor urna. Non auctor, montes nulla distinctio.</p>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="skills">
          <h2>My Skills.</h2>
          <div class="skill-row">
            <img class="" src="" alt="">
            <h3>Lorem & Ipsum</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, quis in duis, iaculis id felis. Consectetuer vestibulum, nunc urna lectus, erat ligula. Hendrerit nam, lectus ante, ut lorem eros.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="skill-row">
            <img class="" src="" alt="">
            <h3>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mauris sed consectetuer. Etiam et eu, bibendum interdum, lacus quis mauris. Curabitur wisi, quisque vel eu, rutrum nam.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="contact-me">
          <h2>Get In Touch</h2>
          <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, non elit.</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in quis, aenean amet. Phasellus sodales, tellus donec dui, ornare erat.</p>
          <a class="btn" href="mailto:name@email.com">CONTACT ME</a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

My css code :

```css
.profile-image{
    display: inline;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Please add your HTML and CSS

Answer (score 0):

You Should use `display:"inline-block"` instead of inline because `display:"inline"` does not accept margin-top and margin-bottom

Comment: but it is still accepting top and bottom margins.                                                                                              and I wanted to why it is happening.

Comment: Share me your link of sandbox, i will look up your problem there.